# How to migrate second Seed or more to Firefly

Tags: wallet, seed, migration, firefly

I did use Trinity since one month and had in it 3 Seeds. Now I did migrate one of the seeds to Firefly and I did want to migrate the second Seed and use a it with Firefly, but I found only the function to Create a second Wallet but not a function to migrate my existing Seed into that Wallet.

How Do I have to handle this Problem as I wish to oversee all my Seeds from Firefly and I wish to migrate them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As firefly uses the BIP39 mnemonic phrases as "seed", there can be more than one wallet attached to (derived from) one mnemonic phrase. However, it is not supported to migrate an existing Trinity seed into a secondary wallet inside a firefly account. Also, it is currently not possible to log into more than one account (and see the balances) at once.

So, at first, you will have to migrate all old seeds individually, resulting in multiple new Firefly "accounts".

After that, if you want to, you can create more wallets in one of the accounts and transfer the IOTA to them from your other (temporary) accounts.

Each of these wallets will use different IOTA addresses, so it is not possible to derive that they all belong to one person when looking at e.g. a Tangle explorer.

But you should keep in mind, that all these wallets are protected by a single mnemonic phrase, so anybody who has access to this phrase will be able to spend all your IOTA from all the attached wallets. So, if your goal of having multiple seeds was to allow others to access the IOTA in one of your seeds and not the others, you will have to stay with multiple accounts and check them separately.

Comment: I did migrate all old seeds individually and transfered these than into a new wallet in the first Fireflyaccount and deletet these migrate-accounts that worked for me. Thanks for the Answer.